# Is economy a tree?

Tags: meaning, expressions, history

It's a typical phrase/expression (?) to say that economy has *branches*:

> "..an industry is a [branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_(economics)) of an economy.." (Wikipedia)

Now does this mean that economy is perceived to be a sort of tree, or a plant? Did they always use this term?

Comment: branch of [fill in subject]: biology, chemistry, physics, etc. etc. The implied structure is that the word sits atop a tree, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your research in Wikipedia is sparse and could profitably have been extended to dictionaries.

> branch = a part of something larger
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/branch)

Hence *industry* is a part of the *economy*, so is a branch of it. My local *M&S shop*s are branches of the whole *M&S company*. *Physics* is a branch of *science*. And *branch* may also be part of a *tree*.

Comment: It probably should be noted that "economy", in this sense, refers to the economic system of a country or culture.  It's not a reference to the "science" of economics.